# Miktex makes generated pdf file executable

Tags: pdftex, miktex, windows

When I compile any `tex` file with `pdflatex` (`MiKTeX-pdfTeX  (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)`) on my windows machine the resulting `log`, `pdf` and `aux` files are marked as executable in the file permissions.

This does not happen when I use `pdflatex` on linux (`pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)`.

What is the reason to make the output files executable?

Is there a possibility to affect the file permissions of the generated files? (globally?)

Comment: Clarification : are they marked as executable in Windows OS or when you copy them back on your Linux ?

Comment: They are marked executable in Windows (Windows 7) (both in the command line (using `icacls`) and in the File-Properties -> Security tab)

Comment: This behavior is not unique to MiKTeX or any TeX. I have seen it before, with some other programs on Windows (10). All of the affected programs are Linux ported to Windows, so maybe the programmer did not take Windows methods of file permissions into account. Sounds like you should raise this issue directly with MiKTeX.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you mean? I'm not really clear what data you are referring to!